# Pagination and filtering on a Laravel API + Nuxt2 +Bootstrap 5 application

Tags: vue.js, datatables, nuxt.js, laravel-api, laravel-pagination

I have several CRUDs on my project and I have been given a layout built using Bootstrap 5.
So I can't use the bootstrap-vue components, as they still use bootstrap 4.
I wanted to use datatables, but I did not find any package for vue 2. I looked for alternatives, but they are all either not free or I am afraid that they would mess with my styles as they use things like Bulma, less or sass.